# Execute another jar in a Java program

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I had written several simple java applications named as A.jar, B.jar.

Now i want to write a GUI java program so that user can press button A to execute A.jar and button B to execute B.jar.

Also i want to output the run-time process detail in my GUI program.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down. Explain to him why his assumptions might be wrong, but don't downvote the question.

Comment: -1 basic Java terminology is not used correctly and question is very vague and leaves a lot for second guessing. Consider re-phrasing your question with more details or simply read about Java classpath and other basics first.

Comment: @grigory: See, that's what you should have asked in the first place, instead of downvoting right away. Downvoting without even asking for more info doesn't do any good...

Comment: @William, sorry for hitting button few seconds later than you did. I reserve my right to voting down with subsequent comment. It's frustrating to see questions asked without basic preparation and/or effort to understand or present the issue. Voting is like a tip at a restaurant to me: you give more or less than standard 12% depending on quality of service. So let's agree to disagree here.

Comment: @topchef I'm 11 years late to this, but you say "It's frustrating to see questions asked without basic preparation...". Then help fix it. Explain *why* you downvoted. Otherwise you aren't helping the problem at all.

Answer (score 85):

If I understand correctly it appears you want to run the jars in a separate process from inside your java GUI application.

To do this you can use:

```
// Run a java app in a separate system process
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar A.jar");
// Then retreive the process output
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
```

Its always good practice to buffer the output of the process.

Comment: Is this solution portable?

Comment: thanks. I've tried exec() func with 3 parameters, including the "dir" parameter and it doesn't work. With only one, we only need to put the 3 files .jar in the same place

Comment: Do you know how to get the `Runtime` object of that java application?

Comment: Can we use a more portable version, using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Cannot run program "java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified. Getting this error.

Comment: This is working, but, if the main project is closed, then, the `A.jar` will be closed

Comment: This answer assumes 'java' is available on the path. What if it is not?

Answer (score 33):

.jar isn't executable. Instantiate classes or make call to any static method.

EDIT:
Add Main-Class entry while creating a JAR.

**>p.mf (content of p.mf)**

> Main-Class: pk.Test

```
>Test.java

package pk;
public class Test{
  public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello from Test");
  }
}
```

Use Process class and it's methods,

```
public class Exec
{
   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
    {
        Process ps=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","A.jar"});
        ps.waitFor();
        java.io.InputStream is=ps.getInputStream();
        byte b[]=new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(b,0,b.length);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is that given access to a jar, how do you add it to the classpath in order to load classes out of it.

Comment: Note: it works only because you have the java bin in your PATH, this is not the case for the default windows installation

Comment: @AVD : where should the A.jar file be kept ?

Comment: @logan - In a directory where you are loading a program.

Comment: Will this approach create a new JVM process or use the existing one?

Answer (score 22):

Hope this helps:

```
public class JarExecutor {

private BufferedReader error;
private BufferedReader op;
private int exitVal;

public void executeJar(String jarFilePath, List<String> args) throws JarExecutorException {
    // Create run arguments for the

    final List<String> actualArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    actualArgs.add(0, "java");
    actualArgs.add(1, "-jar");
    actualArgs.add(2, jarFilePath);
    actualArgs.addAll(args);
    try {
        final Runtime re = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //final Process command = re.exec(cmdString, args.toArray(new String[0]));
        final Process command = re.exec(actualArgs.toArray(new String[0]));
        this.error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(command.getErrorStream()));
        this.op = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream()));
        // Wait for the application to Finish
        command.waitFor();
        this.exitVal = command.exitValue();
        if (this.exitVal != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to execure jar, " + this.getExecutionLog());
        }

    } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new JarExecutorException(e);
    }
}

public String getExecutionLog() {
    String error = "";
    String line;
    try {
        while((line = this.error.readLine()) != null) {
            error = error + "\n" + line;
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
    String output = "";
    try {
        while((line = this.op.readLine()) != null) {
            output = output + "\n" + line;
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
    try {
        this.error.close();
        this.op.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
    return "exitVal: " + this.exitVal + ", error: " + error + ", output: " + output;
}
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes 'java' is available on the path. What if it is not?

Answer (score 2):

The following works by starting the jar with a batch file, in case the program runs as a stand alone:

```
public static void startExtJarProgram(){
        String extJar = Paths.get("C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\batchfile.bat").toString();
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(extJar);
        processBuilder.redirectError(new File(Paths.get("C:\\path\\to\\JavaProcessOutput\\extJar_out_put.txt").toString()));
        processBuilder.redirectInput();
        try {
           final Process process = processBuilder.start();
            try {
                final int exitStatus = process.waitFor();
                if(exitStatus==0){
                    System.out.println("External Jar Started Successfully.");
                    System.exit(0); //or whatever suits 
                }else{
                    System.out.println("There was an error starting external Jar. Perhaps path issues. Use exit code "+exitStatus+" for details.");
                    System.out.println("Check also C:\\path\\to\\JavaProcessOutput\\extJar_out_put.txt file for additional details.");
                    System.exit(1);//whatever
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException: "+ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException. Faild to start process. Reason: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Process Terminated.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

In the batchfile.bat then we can say:

```
@echo off
start /min C:\path\to\jarprogram.jar
```

Comment: Thanks @Dawood Morris This is really helpful when your jar requires some considerable amount of resources like memory etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the jar's in your classpath, and you know its Main class, you can just invoke the main class.  Using DITA-OT as an example:

```
import org.dita.dost.invoker.CommandLineInvoker;
....
CommandLineInvoker.main('-f', 'html5', '-i', 'samples/sequence.ditamap', '-o', 'test')
```

Note this will make the subordinate jar share memory space and a classpath with your jar, with all the potential for interference that can cause.  If you don't want that stuff polluted, you have other options, as mentioned above - namely:

- create a new ClassLoader with the jar in it.  This is more safe; you can at least isolate the new jar's knowledge to a core classloader if you architect things with the knowledge that you'll be making use of alien jars.  It's what we do in my shop for our plugins system; the main application is a tiny shell with a ClassLoader factory, a copy of the API, and knowledge that the real application is the first plugin for which it should build a ClassLoader.  Plugins are a pair of jars - interface and implementation - that are zipped up together.  The ClassLoaders all share all the interfaces, while each ClassLoader only has knowledge of its own implementation.  The stack's a little complex, but it passes all tests and works beautifully.
- use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(...)` (which wholly isolates the jar, but has the normal "find the application", "escape your strings right", "platform-specific WTF", and "OMG System Threads" pitfalls of running system commands.

Answer (score 1):

First we cerate a class FirstFileOutput having a main method that outputs a line to stable output and a line to stable error. With all first procedure, we'll again create a class RuntimeExecCheck that will run our FirstFileOutput class in starting for process, and after that RuntimeExecCheck class will read the stable output and the stable error from FirstFileOutput and output comes.

```
package check;

public class FirstFileOutput{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is output to stable output");
        System.err.println("This is output to stable error");
    }
}



package check;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RuntimeExecCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("java -classpath C:\\projects\\workspace\\check\\bin check.FirstFileOutput");
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
            InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader(errorStream);

            int n1;
            char[] c1 = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer stableOutput = new StringBuffer();
            while ((n1 = isr.read(c1)) > 0) {
                stableOutput.append(c1, 0, n1);
            }
            System.out.println("Stable Output: " + stableOutput.toString());

            int n2;
            char[] c2 = new char[1024];
            StringBuffer stableError = new StringBuffer();
            while ((n2 = esr.read(c2)) > 0) {
                stableError.append(c2, 0, n2);
            }
            System.out.println("Stable Error: " + stableError.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes 'java' is available on the path. What if it is not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command_string);
    BufferedInputStream successBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
    BufferedInputStream errorBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(process.getErrorStream());
    synchronized (process) {
        process.waitFor();
    }

    if (errorBufferedInputStream.available() != ZERO) {
        errorBufferedInputStream.close();
        System.out.println("error stream after jar execution");
    }

    if (process.exitValue() != ZERO) {
       System.out.println("error jar execution");
    }

    if (successBufferedInputStream.available() == ZERO) {
       System.out.println("error");
    }

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while ((successBufferedInputStream.available()) > ZERO) {
        response.append((char) successBufferedInputStream.read());
    }
    successBufferedInputStream.close();
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are java 1.6 then the following can also be done:

```
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler; 
import javax.tools.ToolProvider; 

public class CompilerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileToCompile = "/Users/rupas/VolatileExample.java";

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);

        if (compilationResult == 0) {
            System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question