# How to run a jar file from a separate jar file?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute another jar in a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program)

Basically I want to run an external .jar from the one I'm working on now.

I.e. I want to run foo.jar from bar.jar

I've tried using `Runtime` and `Process` to execute "java -jar foo.jar", but it opens foo.jar and then it closes immediately. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution ([as Thorn pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545497/152661)) would be to have the jar as a build-time dependency and invoke it statically from your code:

```
ExternalJarMainClass.main(new String[]{"arguments", "to", "main"});
```

But if that is not possible, you can use a `URLClassLoader` to load the jar dynamically. If the jar is indeed runnable, then you can read the main class from  `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`  and invoke `main` via reflection.

This is a different approach from creating a separate process, as the external code will run in the same process as your application. Perhaps this is desirable, perhaps not - that depends on the situation.

Below's a (hastily written and flawed) sample helper class that does just that.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JarRunner {

    private final Method entryPoint;

    public JarRunner(File jarFile) throws
            ClassNotFoundException,
            IOException,
            NoSuchMethodException {
        URL jarUrl = jarFile.toURI().toURL();
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                new URL[]{jarUrl});
        URL manifestUrl = loader.findResource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
        String manifest = resourceToString(manifestUrl);
        Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass(findMainClassName(manifest));
        entryPoint = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    }

    public void run(String[] argsToMain) throws
            IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException,
            InvocationTargetException {
        entryPoint.invoke(null, (Object) argsToMain);
    }

    private static String resourceToString(URL url) throws IOException {
        InputStream contentStream = url.openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(contentStream));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            do {
                line = r.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append('\n');
                }
            } while (line != null);
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            contentStream.close();
        }
    }

    private static String findMainClassName(String manifest) {
        Matcher m = MAIN_CLASS_PATTERN.matcher(manifest);
        if (m.find()) {
            return m.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final Pattern MAIN_CLASS_PATTERN = 
            Pattern.compile("Main-Class: (.+)");
}
```

Sample usage:

```
JarRunner jr = new JarRunner(new File("path/to/MyJar.jar"));
jr.run(new String[]{"arg1", "arg2"});
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you run foo.jar directly?  Does it have a manifest with a main method?

I am guessing that you can.  So you want to launch the main method inside of a class like foo.Main

**Option 1:** Include foo.jar in the classpath.  If you are using an IDE, then this just means adding foo.jar as a library.  Now you are free to import the package (lets call the package foo) and launch your second java program from a single line of Java code:
foo.Main.main(null);
Most likely you would want to do this in a separate thread:

```
class FooRunner extends Thread { 
   public void run() { 
       foo.Main.main(null);
   } 
}
```

and then you would launch with this:

```
FooRunner secondaryApp = new FooRunner();
secondaryApp.start();
```

**Option 2**
You can load the classes in the Foo package at runtime using a class loader.
See the Javadocs for java.lang.ClassLoader and [this example of a CustomClassLoader](http://codethesis.com/sites/default/index.php?servlet=4&content=1)

Answer (score 1):

Check `java -jar foo.jar` runs correctly from command line. Also ensure java is there in the path.  It may be better to provide absolute path to `java.exe` in the arguments.

Please consider using `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime`.