# CMD commands in other OS systems

Tags: java, linux, windows, command, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute another jar in a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program)

I am making a program that run from a java document, and runs a Java document.
I am using windows and

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c \"cd %appdata%\\.gknl && java -jar launcher.jar\""
);
```

works for me fine, but on linux,Mac etc it wont work,

Can someone help me to fix the other OS systems?

Note: i already have a check for the OS...

Comment: Don't run the program like that, use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux:

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"csh","-c","cd " + appdata +"\.gknl &&  java -jar launcher.jar");
```

Comment: csh is not installed on all Linux systems. I have 4 systems in front of me and I only have it on 1. If you want to be assured that something will work, you use sh. That is on my Ubuntu, both Fedoras, and my Raspian system.

Comment: I install csh anywhere I have to do work  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux/Unix you want to use sh. This will be linked on most systems to bash, zsh, or csh.

I am 95% sure that sh is also on the Mac, but I'd need to unplug my Raspberry Pi and put everything back into my Mac Mini to verify.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` is the Windows shell executable, you will need to use one of the Linux/Mac shells:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "sh", "-c",
        "cd $appdata/.gknl && java -jar launcher.jar");
pb.start();
```

If `launcher.jar` is on the classpath, it should be possible to launch the main application class from the calling application however without using `Process/ProcessBuilder`.