# Run a jar from a class

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run a jar from a java class, how could I do that? Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java --jar grok.jar");
}
```

I'd be running this from within my IDE, eclipse. I'm not sure how to use the returned process to check the result of the command. It would also be nice if I could direct the output of the jar to a location of my choosing. This could probably be accomplished using "process.getOutputStream()", but since the jar will launch a blocking process, not sure how that would work?

Thanks

Comment: To direct the "_output of the jar_" to a location of your choosing, you'll probably want to add logic to your "_jarred_" program.  For example, you might pass the output location as an argument.  Seems to me this is the portable way to implement this.  You could do something like `java --jar grok.jar > output-file`, but I don't know if that would work on Windows (like most things it would probably work everywhere else).  That said, I'm not sure you can redirect output through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program). Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320485/2047424) for example, it should give you an idea on how to start a process and get the output as an InputStream.

```
    Process ps=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","A.jar"});
    ps.waitFor();
    java.io.InputStream is=ps.getInputStream();
```

Comment: You'd better stop your code sample after the third line. The other ones are plain wrong. That's not how you read everything from an input stream.