# How to run jar file from inside a class?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I want to run a program using the following commands

```
java Main -host arg1 arg2
```

However I have faced some troble as I had made the project in separate packages. So I get a jar file and cannot run the main from the above keywords. I have to call the jar file thus from the command line.

```
java -jar Main.jar arg1 arg2
```

However I do not want that as it goes against my specification.

Can you help me please?

SPECIFICATION

A text-only application is all that is required. It must be networked and run as either a host (server) or a
client from the command line using the commands:

```
java BankApp -host PORT
java BankApp -client MACHINE PORT
```

to start as host or client respectively. For example, if you know the host is running on aloha at port 8888
you would connect with:

```
java BankApp -client aloha 8888
```

what I need to do to run is as follows.

```
java -jar C:\Users\UniversityofBristol\Desktop\BankApp\BankApp\dist BankApp.jar arg1 arg2
```

public class BankApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


    String current = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    current = "java -jar " + current + "\\dist";
    current = "\"" + current + "\"";
    current = current + " BankApp.jar";
    System.out.println("Current dir:" + current);

    // Run a java app in a separate system process
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(current);
    // Then retreive the process output
    InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();

}
```

}

Comment: If i knew about your specification, i could have helped!

Comment: Hi, I just uploaded the spec!

Comment: @AdityaSaxena - have a look at the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), the javaDoc has a good example on how to start processes. Note, that the executable and the arguments are all in separate Strings!

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program) if you want to run the .jar in a separate process.

Otherwise I think you can just add it to your project (look under project properties in whatever IDE you are using) and use it as any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your jar on the classpath. You could break the spec a little bit, by saying:

```
java -cp bankapp.jar BankApp arg1 arg2
```

or set the $CLASSPATH environment variable (which is ugly and I never really do it outside scripts but it works):

```
export CLASSPATH=path/to/your/jar
java BankApp arg1 arg2
```

**Spoiler**

- [Setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: Thanks! But I have to add no aditional arguments. I tried creating a dummy BankApp Class and tried to call the jarfile from it.

Comment: -cp bankapp.jar is not allowed. I have seen that. It has to be java BankApp -host arg1 arg2...

Comment: Then use the second approach (define the CLASSPATH variable). Is your spec really *that* strict that you aren't allowed to add java vm options?

Comment: Trying that ! thanks if it works will send a message in some time. Need to read it. Have never done before.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments

Comment: @AdityaSaxena - Could you edit your question and paste the code that causes this exception?