# Running a jar file located on Raspberry PI from a remote machine (My computer)

Tags: java, servlets, jar

I have been trying to execute jar files. I first learnt how to execute them through cmd and I did fairly well. Now, I am currently trying to run the jar file from Java code that I have been writing. The jar is located in my machine and I run the jar through jar code as shown below:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
p = r.exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "start C:\\jartest\\JavaApplication.jar" });
```

This works really good on my machine. The output of JavaApplication.jar is that it creates a folder and the output is achieved.

The problem occurs, when I want to run a Jar file located at Raspberry PI from my machine through Servlet. The code is as shown below:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    QLM qlm = new QLM();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        out.println("Response of Servlet Content Started \n");
        String message= request.getParameter("msg");
        out.println(message);
        if((qlm.get_Envelop(message))!= null){
            out.println("DATA IS VALID");
        } else out.println("WRONG MESSAGE!!");
        out.println("Response of Servlet Content end \n");

        **Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        out.println("Am I here??");
        r.exec(new String[] {"cmd","/c", "start /home/pi/JARTest/JavaApplication24.jar", "file1" });**
        out.println("Did it work??");

    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

It is the same jar file that was on my Machine. I put/store JavaApplication.jar on PI through WinSCP. The path where the jar located on Raspberry PI is: **/home/pi/JARTest**. I pass the command line argument as "file1" to the Jar file. The other operations of servlet works fine as well, except from running the Jar file.

P.S- The result of the jar (JavaApplication.jar) is same. It works on my machine (Windows), but it simply doesn't want to accept the same jar file and the same command Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); on Raspberry PI.

Please help me with this. Any input/suggestions/ideas will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither Java nor jar are acronyms. Java is capitalized  as it is a proper noun. Jar is not capitalized, as it is not. I edited it.

Comment: @vy32 Thanks for the edit :) Will keep in mind from the next posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
 r.exec(new String[] {
    "cmd","/c", "start /home/pi/JARTest/JavaApplication24.jar", "file1" });
```

That is Windows code. It calls "cmd", the Windows command shell. So that won't work on other OS (like the Linux on your Pi).

Try to [rewrite it using the "java" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program).

Comment: I tried to do the same using the java command. It doesn't work either. I tried this : r.exec(new String[] {"java -jar /home/pi/JARTest/JavaApplication24.jar", "file1"})

Comment: What errors are you getting? Maybe you need a full path to `java`? And try to separate the program name from the arguments ("java", "-jar /home...", "file1");

Comment: It doesn't give any error (thatss what is making it hard). Now it prints both the out.println's, but it doesn't give me the result of the execution of jar.

Comment: By doing this: 
out.println(r.exec(new String[] {"java", "-jar", "/home/pi/JARTest/JavaApplication24.jar"}));

It prints me a Garbage value/ Junk value