# How to execute a jar file within a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have a project who's structure cannot be changed. What i have to do is that

I have a main jar file that have directores

```
/classes
/lib
/main
/manifest
```

I have to call a Test1 class when i execute the main jar file. so in the manifest file i gave the path of the Main-Class : path.to.file.

I have another jar file inside the `main` folder that contains the actual application. What can i do to execute the jar in main folder and execute its `Test2` class mentioned in the Manifest file.

Please give me a solution or any direction to work on. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Here is a link that may help you in your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program

Comment: @AdrianTotolici The answers in your link does not handle jars in jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this in the current ClassLoader, you need a new one.

If your jar named `foobar.jar` and you have a `main`-method in the class `test.abc.Main` this may work:

```
    URL[] urls={new URL("classloader:/main/foobar.jar")};
    ClassLoader parentClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URLClassLoader childClassLoader=new URLClassLoader(urls,parentClassLoader);
    Class clazz = childClassLoader.loadClass("test.abc.Main");
    String[] arguments = new String[]{};
    clazz.getMethod("main", arguments.getClass()).invoke(null,arguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use JarClassLoader http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php if you're okay with using GPLv3'd code to make a launcher class.
2. Extract the jars inside of the main jar to a temporary location, execute and delete upon exit
3. Simply change the file structure, since you haven't listed any reasons for "not doing that", I don't see why not. :D