# Invoke java class in jar from code

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar created by maven with all dependencies in it. I have another java code that wants to use the jar as a library. My java code and the classes in the jar belong to two different packages.

The following shows how I am running the main class in the jar:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/test/resources/log4j2.xml 
     -cp pathtojars com.mainclass "parameters to mainclass" "inputfile"
```

How can i invoke the main class in the jar (equivalent of the above command) and get its STDOUT as a variable after execution is complete in my java code?

Comment: Ok, and what is the question

Comment: @Dici Question updated.

Comment: Before trying to answer you, I have a question. Why should you run this Java code as an external application whereas your code is in Java ? Usually, you do this to interface a program written with another language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute another jar in a java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program)

Comment: You can get more idea from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki

Comment: @Dici How else can i invoke the main of a java class in a jar from another jar?

Comment: @Karan what stopped you from using my answer ?

Comment: @Dici I was just answering the question you had above about why should i run this java code as an external application.

Comment: @Karan Ok, I just meant that calling Java code from a Java code is a pretty common thing to do :D Usually to use classes in a jar you just add the jar to your classpath and then write your code !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ProcessBuilder` to do this kind of things, but whether or not you should call a Java program from another Java program is another question :

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/test/resources/log4j2.xml", "-cp", "pathtojars com.mainclass", "\"parameters to mainclass\"", "\"inputfile\"").start();
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: So the requirement is that i need to package the calling class also into a jar. Then when i run this main jar which in turn invokes the library jar, does it have to be placed in a certain location to be able to call the library jar?

Comment: Not really, as long as you set the working directory of the `ProcessBuilder` to the right place

Comment: Ass dici mentioned what you are trying to read is output (console output) of a process execution

Comment: @Acewin You should post your own answer instead of editing mine

Comment: @Dici When i am trying to read the output stream as a buffered stream like:-

BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(os));

I get the error: error: no suitable constructor found for InputStreamReader(OutputStream)

Comment: @Karan This is a compile error, and a pretty easy one. Just one the Javadoc as well as example of usage of `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if you simply want to read console output you can do something like this

```
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/test/resources/log4j2.xml", "-cp", "pathtojars com.mainclass", "\"parameters to mainclass\"", "\"inputfile\"");
String OUTPUT_FILE = "C:/temp/testFile.txt";
File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
procBuilder.redirectOutput(outFile);
Process process = procBuilder.start();
outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(outFile, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(content);
```

Or you can also write something like this [ProcessBuilder: Forwarding stdout and stderr of started processes without blocking the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165517/processbuilder-forwarding-stdout-and-stderr-of-started-processes-without-blocki)

As dici pointed out you first need to get the OutPutStream of the process and handle it in the way you want to.