# Java Orchestration

Tags: java, ant

I got 5 different .JAR's that I want to "run" with Apache Ant. I would like to give each of them some kind of "Order"-ID, (1 to 5) and have one JAR that runs all the other fives if they are selected.

Example: Component1, Component2, Component3, Component4, Component5 should be in the folder "job". I got a file called order.properties which looks like this: ComponentA = true, ComponentB = false and so on. Main.Jar should read order.properties and run all the Components that are "true" in the order that they are listed in the properties file.

I don't have any clue if thats possible and how because I simply don't know where to start looking for.

Comment: Why don't you just read the `order.properties` file and then execute the jars? You could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program

Comment: Learn about how to specify a classpath

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll read through those topics. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run tasks.

```
 <java classname="test.Main">
     <arg value="-h"/>
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="dist/test.jar"/>
       <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
     </classpath>
   </java>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html