# How to execute the jar file from a java class

Tags: java

I am having the java main application which needs to execute another jar file and return it without waiting for the jar execution complete. Is it possible to achieve it using Java. Can anyone give some inputs in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar <PATH_OF _JAR>");
```

in your Main class.

And as @Yoav has suggested. You need to take care of errors by adopting proper error handling strategy.

Do Read - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm

Comment: note that several types of exceptions might be thrown if the command was unsuccessful or not found - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm

Comment: Yes true.  Proper error Handling is required.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar <PATH_OF _JAR>"); return.  Will it trigger the jar and return my main function immediately?

Comment: Need to try that